# php5 ini file is blank

Tags: debian-wheezy, php5

I have been building a Debian machine for test (Wheezy, x64) and have installed php5 and apache and successfully run `phpinfo()` to the browser, and `php -v` to the command line.

From the details in `phpinfo()`, the location of the `Loaded Configuration File` is `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.  However when I list that file I see that it is empty! (This is one of two `php.ini` files on the computer, the other is the expected `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, which is also empty)

My expectation is that the file should be around 70k in size (see [php.ini for my php installation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.4.14/php.ini-production))

I have tried `apt-get install --reinstall php5` to try an fix things .. but it didn't, and it didn't replace the only php.ini files I know about.

So where is my ini file or how do I install the proper one?

I could download the matching file from Git, but that doesn't seem to be the correct way of addressing my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I have no idea what went wrong with the installation, but it was cured with:

```
apt-get remove php5*
apt-get install php5
```

The key thing was purging the php5 files

Comment: man, thanks for posting this, I had some problem, this solved it, I spent a whole day on it. thanks u very much !!!